# Inserting Data with Identity_Insert is ON with Insert into Table1 Select * from Table2

Tags: sql, identity

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (id int IDENTITY (1,1), name nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO TestTable(name) VALUES ('data1');                     
INSERT INTO TestTable(name) VALUES ('data2');                       
Declare @Identity as int
set @identity=IDENT_CURRENT ('TestTable') 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestTable ON;
```

How i can achieve this functionality ?

```
INSERT INTO TestTable
Select * from 
(
Select 55 as a,'data55' as b
Union
Select 56 as a,'data55' as b
)n
```

When this is replaced then ..
Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'TestTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (id, name) VALUES (55, 'data55');     
INSERT INTO TestTable (id, name) VALUES (56, 'data55');    

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestTable OFF;
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TestTable, reseed,@identity )
INSERT INTO TestTable(name) VALUES ('data3');                 
Select * from TestTable 
Drop table TestTable
```

Comment: Read the error message again: "... can only be specified when a column list is used **and** IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.". In your union example, you're not providing a column list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to say

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (id, name)
Select * from  
( 
Select 55 as a,'data55' as b 
Union 
Select 56 as a,'data55' as b 
)n
```

Comment: My requirement is a Ferrari and a mansion in the country. That doesn't affect the rules of the language.

Answer (score 8):

This should work properly:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestTable ON;

INSERT INTO TestTable(id, name)
Select * 
from 
( 
    Select 55 as a, 'data55' as b 
    Union 
    Select 56 as a, 'data55' as b 
)n;
```

Just set `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` with the fields listed in the `INSERT` clause.